# asp:gridview textbox old value is post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

```
<asp:GridView Width="300px" RowStyle-Height="20px" HeaderStyle-Height="25px" DataKeyNames="Id"  ID="bankAccounts_List" CssClass="table" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sorting Handle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
<ItemTemplate>
<span class="handle"><img src="../Images/sortingHandler.jpg" height="10" /></span>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account Number">                                              
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="grd_txtbankAccountNumber" Width="150" onblur="return OnBlurGridTextbox(this);" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="White" style="text-align:left;" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="grd_txtPriority" Width="100" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="White" runat="server" style="text-align:center"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="grd_linkbutton" OnClientClick="return EditGridButton(this)">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" >
<HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
<ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="grd_lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>                                       
</asp:GridView>  

<asp:Button ID="btnSaveBankInformation" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Strings,save%>"
            OnClick="btnSaveBankInformation_Click" />

protected void btnSaveBankInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextBox txtBankAccountNumber = bankAccounts_List.Rows[i].Cells[GetColumnIndexByName(bankAccounts_List.Rows[i], "Account Number")].FindControl("grd_txtbankAccountNumber") as TextBox;
}
```

What ever I change in any of the textbox, On save button I always gets the old binded textbox value not the New value I just entered.
Kindly Help me. and yes i am not binding GridView on PostBack again using `!IsPostBack`

Comment: Side-note: you don't need to use `FindControl` on the cell. It's sufficient to use `bankAccounts_List.Rows[i].FindControl("grd_txtbankAccountNumber")` because the row is it's `NamingContainer`.

Comment: What is `OnBlurGridTextbox`? Show your `Page_Load` anyway, even if you claim that you use `!IsPostBack`, we want to see it ;)

Comment: Are you doing this `if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }`
 as Mr @TimSchmelter said

Comment: Why you are using this: 'TextBox txtBankAccountNumber = ...'? You are just getting the TextBox, but you aren't setting the Text property, I mean, you are just holding your control on memory...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!IsPostBack) //Bind grid only when IsPostBack is false
{
    grd.DataSource = //data source ;
    grd.DataBind(); // bind data 
}
```

Comment: _"and yes i am not binding GridView on PostBack again using !IsPostBack"_